# Unit test wiring of MVC, FluentValidation, and Ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, fluentvalidation

I have set up an MVC web project with FluentValidation and Ninject using the Ninject.Extensions.Mvc.FluentValidation package.  I followed the documentation of that package directly.

I'd like to write an automated test that verifies this wiring, and checks that the model validation will use the FluentValidation validators as expected.  I'm having a hard time spinning up the right pieces of the MVC application in my test in order to do this.

Basically, I want to spin up the MVC app enough so that the Ninject kernel is created, the model binders are wired, and validators are created.  Then I want to try to validate an entity through the MVC model validation and make sure that expected messages from the validator are showing up.

What is the best way to automating the testing of the interaction between Ninject, MVC, and FluentValidation?

Comment: You need integration tests when you need to verify components interaction.

Comment: Yes fine.  Integration tests.  I'm not debating testing terminology I'm looking for how to solve this specific test case.

Answer (score 2):

I have similar setup but I use Unity instead of Ninject.

My IoC container inherits UnityContainer where I register all my repos, validarots, etc. I benefit from this because I have validators with repo dependencies (e.g. UserRegistrationValidator checks for unique user names).

My IoC container also implements [IValidatorFactory](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ValidatorFactory&referringTitle=Documentation). I use it register a global ModelValidatorProvider like this:

```
var ioc = new IoCContainer();
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider(ioc));
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
```

With this setup I know that my validators will intercept model validation in controller actions but only if validators are resolved by ValidatorFactory.

So basically I have 2 groups of tests

### - IoC tests

With these I test if my IoC container can resolve a validator for a model. With Unity it looks something like this:

```
// Arrange
var ioc = new IoCContainer();

// Assert
Assert.IsTrue(ioc.IsRegistered(IValidator<MyModel>));
```

If you have all your models under one namespace you could even write a single unit test by getting all types from specific namespace and check if IValidator is registered for them in a loop.

### - Validator tests

These are common tests to test my (view)models:

```
// Arrange
var validator = new MyModelValidator();
var model = new MyModel{ Name = null };

// Assert
validator.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(x => x.Name, model)
```

With this there is no need to spin application, you just test what you create.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 It's good to break it out into unit tests like this rather than to go for browser-based integration tests (although there is a place for a few of those).

Comment: Totally agree on this approach to testing.  So yes you test the container to make sure it is working, and you test the validators to make sure those are working.  I have those tests.  What I'm looking to do is to write a test that makes sure the *wiring of the validator factory to MVC* is working.  Perhaps it is not necessary with all of the other tests you describe.  But I was looking to see if it was possible.

Comment: Well, testing _wiring_ itself would require to boot up all MVC infrastructure, so that would basically mean to test through your app's UI. Calls to static classes are involved to wire up  custom validation and to test _that_ you would need some kind of wrapper. But then again it's hard to test if your wrapper gets called. I personally see this as testing if your areas or global filters are registered. And would I need this kind of test? I think no because you would notice any flaws in early development stages

Comment: Testing wiring through UI would be misleading for me because UI might change any time and that would definitely make those tests fail when all the wiring would be the same and most probably intact. So summa summarum I would not write any tests for wiring itself ... at least until first failure. How would I test then? To be honest I don' know

Answer (score 2):

What we use here for the integration test is [Selenium Webdriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/), you can get it with NuGet. We write code usign [page pattern](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) so it's easyer to maintain.

When I want to check if a requiered field or any other custom validation I do the following :

```
    [TestFixture]
    public class CenterTests : TestBase
    {

        [Test]
        public void CreateViewAndEditShouldWork()
        {   
            S.OpenWithCI();
            var loginPage = new LoginPage(S);
            var homePage = loginPage.LoginValidUser("email", "Password");
            var centerListPage = homePage.ClickCenterAndRoomLink();
            var centerPage = centerListPage.ClickCreateLink();

            //Create
            centerPage.CreateInvalidCenter();
            Assert.That(S.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span[for=Name]")).Text, Is.StringContaining(Strings.Error_Required));
            Assert.That(S.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span[for=EnglishName]")).Text, Is.StringContaining(Strings.Error_Required));

            centerListPage = centerPage.CreateValidCenter("Saguenay", "Sag", "2089 blv Talbot");
            Thread.Sleep(2000); 
            S.ExpectSuccessNotice(Strings.CenterCreatedSuccessfully);
        }
    }
```

And here's the code of my TestBase helper class :

```
namespace Afi.AutomatedTests.Helpers
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class TestBase
    {
        protected IWebDriver S;

        [SetUp]
        public virtual void TestSetup()
        {
            S = new ChromeDriver();
            S.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1024, 768);
            S.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            S.Quit();
        }

        public string GetUrl(string relativePath)
        {
            if(!relativePath.StartsWith("/"))
                throw new ArgumentException("Relative URL must begins with /");

            return "http://afi.local" + relativePath;
        }
    }
}
```

All those tests are in an other project call AutomatedTests and I can run them the same way I run unit test (resharper/nunit). It uses Chromedriver to do the tests.

Let me know if you need more informations.